# Mathematical relation between shear stress and temperature

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer

I have recently started research in mechanical engineering. Currently I am working in the field of **friction stir welding**. During my study I came across a point where I have to find the **mathematical relation between shear stress and temperature during plastic deformation of material**. I tried to find out about it on *google* but did not get satisfactory answer. Can anyone please explain about it?

To be specific, I am performing Friction stir welding on aluminum during which the temperature is going to be in the range 473-700 Kelvin.

It is a difficult question for me hopefully not for others.

Comment: This question as it stands is excessively broad. The behavior of each of those independent effects (shear stress, temperature, and plastic deformation) is highly dependent on the desired material. The combined behavior then is completely out of reach without greater specification.

Comment: I agree with the @Wasabi, I suggest specifying at least 2-3 example materials and even temperature range(s). This will narrow the question to one that will receive responses.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a mathematical relationship like you are looking for. I have only seen curves plotted by testing specific materials.